# Is there a way to disable Tiny Scrolling for just one div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, fancybox

Didn't want to create a new question so I'll just refrase this one,
is there a way to disable the Tiny Scrolling plugin for just one particular div?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting the "centerOnScroll" variable to true ([ref](http://fancybox.net/api))?

```
$('#selector').fancybox({
 centerOnScroll : true
})
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! i don't think this is what i'm looking for, i can't test the script since i'm not at home but the reason is that i'm guessing this will center the fancybox, which wont stop the tinyscrolling plugin from scrolling to the box.

Comment: Setting that variable makes fancybox center the viewbox when you scroll the page in any direction. If that isn't what you want, then maybe I have misunderstood what you need.